# LEFT JOIN trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm probably missing something, but I can't make a simple SQL query work.
I have 2 tables City and Event and I want to see all cities that hosted any event.
The code below seems to perform something odd, because it just overloads PHPMyAdmin.

```
SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
FROM city 
LEFT JOIN event ON city.id = event.city
```

When I tried natural join, it displayed all events that were hosted in any city as expected.

Comment: try out `SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
    FROM city 
    INNER JOIN event ON city.id = event.city
    GROUP BY city.name`, I have no MySql to check this

Comment: The DB machine seems to be working like if it would be returning billions of rows, but it doesn't return any result.

Comment: Can you share your table creation queries as well? Because I think you might be missing some indices..

Comment: @sll, thank you very much, it works! Can you explain to me, why the LEFT JOIN does not?

Comment: @ melihcelik- it was created using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You can connect to MySQL using some tool, like MySQL Workbench and run `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`city\`` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`event\`` to see the queries.

Comment: @user965748 my answer has a link to information about different join types, should help you with this question

Comment: @user965748 : I have added my answer see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two things:

- Make it an `INNER` join (don't use the `LEFT` keyword)
- Use the `DISTINCT` keyword, otherwise you'll get the same city returned many times (once for each event it hosted)

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
FROM city 
JOIN event ON city.id = event.city
```

You could also accomplish this using a sub-select, like this:

```
SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
FROM city
WHERE id in (SELECT city from EVENT)
```

Personally, I find the sub-select easier to understand - it's almost like the English you used to describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to see cities that hosted an event, use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.  The latter will show all cities regardless of whether an event was held.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it with a left join, but I don't see the point -- just use an inner join and do a distinct.

```
SELECT distinct city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
FROM city 
LEFT JOIN event ON city.id = event.city
where event.city is not null
```

With inner join

```
SELECT distinct city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
FROM city 
JOIN event ON city.id = event.city
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.name, c.date, c.gh, c.ga 
FROM city AS c
INNER JOIN event AS e ON c.id = e.city
```

Take a look at this graphical explanation on [JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), should help you out.

If you only want distinct City names that have had events, you could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name
FROM city AS c
INNER JOIN event AS e ON c.id = e.city
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga 
FROM city 
INNER JOIN event ON city.id = event.city
GROUP BY city.name
```

The LEFT JOIN will return you all entries from city table even no event entry is associated, the output resultset would be pretty big, using INNER JOIN you requesting only rows which has an associated entry, and by doing GROUP BY you select single row per city so you would end up with a list of unique Cities which has any event associated in the events table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to express this in SQL, and you should profile to find out which way works best with your database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga
  FROM city
  INNER JOIN event ON event.city = city.id

SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga
  FROM city
  INNER JOIN event ON event.city = city.id
  GROUP BY city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga

SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga
  FROM city
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT event.city FROM event
  ) AS eventcity ON eventcity.city = city.id

SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga
  FROM city
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT event.city FROM event GROUP BY event.city
  ) AS eventcity ON eventcity.city = city.id

SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga
  FROM city
  WHERE city.id IN (SELECT event.city FROM event)

SELECT city.name, city.date, city.gh, city.ga
  FROM city
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT city FROM event WHERE event.city = city.id)
```